# spring-boot and ./config directory

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm not certain anymore about how Spring-boot exactly handles environment, properties file and config location.

**Use case**

Below the result docker container of my spring-boot application

Docker container

```
 /
 |- spring-boot-app.jar
 |- /config/
 |--|- application.properties
 |--|- logback-spring.xml
```

I also use environment variables

**The problem**

The `logback-spring.xml` isn't read by Spring-boot.
To make it so I HAVE TO add `LOGGING_CONFIG=config/logback-spring.xml`

Shouldn't Spring-boot look for logback-spring.xml automatically under this directory ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Spring Documentation (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html) it says:

> The various logging systems can be activated by including the
>   appropriate libraries on the classpath, and further customized by
>   providing a suitable configuration file **in the root of the classpath**,
>   or in a location specified by the Spring Environment property
>   logging.config.

So if you put the file directly beneath spring-boot-app.jar it should work without configuration of `logging.config`.

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot automatically loads application.properties and application.yaml from below locations, Values from lower-order overriding earlier ones

1. The classpath root
2. The classpath /config package
3. The current directory
4. The /config subdirectory in the current directory
5. Immediate child directories of the /config subdirectory